# django admin list page

Tags: django

Iam working in django-admin. In Django admin list page, I need to insert field name customatically near to actions.
For this customization, I need the django template for admin list page

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding admin templates is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). You need to copy `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html` (from the django source) to `templates/admin/change_list.html` (your template directory)

Comment: can u give me example to override the template for adding the field outer to list_display.