# django admin list page view

Tags: django, django-admin

How to customize django admin list page using views and how to pass values in template change_list.html to display new field as in [django admin list page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611494/django-admin-list-page)

I tried to write list view in admin as:

```
def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(BeneficiaryAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^list_view/$', self.list_view)
        )
        return my_urls + urls

def list_view(self, request):
        print "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"
        # custom view which should return an HttpResponse
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/member_management/beneficiary/")
```

But list_view is not callable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)?

Comment: I tried the coding of get_urls and my_view for the list view page. For viewing the page, i need to write admin views. Can u give 1 example?

Answer (score 0):

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
        cl = ChangeList(request, self.model, list(self.list_display), 
                        self.list_display_links, self.list_filter, 
                        self.date_hierarchy, self.search_fields,  
                        self.list_select_related, 
                        self.list_per_page, 
                        self.list_editable, 
                        self)

        if extra_context is None: 
            extra_context = {}
return super(BeneficiaryAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

We can edit the list view page using this.